# Push Notification Server in Java

Tags: windows-phone-7, push-notification, mpns

Microsoft describes a method to create a push notification service in C#. 
But I rather want to run a Java service for this is that possible at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely. It's just a matter of making an HTTP/HTTPS request to Microsoft. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202945%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) shows the headers and payloads to be sent.